# SQL Server Management Studio SSMS 18.0 General Availability release (GA) install fails

Tags: sql-server, ssms, installation

**Requirement**

I wish to install SSMS 18.0 GA (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017), on Windows 10 but get error:

[image]

**Uninstall Preview**

Attempt to uninstall 18.0 preview via Add/Remove programs:

[image]

Uninstall fails with:

*"The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable"*

*"Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'vs2017_isoshell_for_ssms.msi' in the box below"*

Use source C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{D620DE9C-8A83-4BA5-83A8-E709A4150A47}v15.0.27248.2015\redist\

vs2017_isoshell_for_ssms.msi does not exist on my machine.

[image]

**Other fixes attempted**

I attempted to remove via other means:

- I have run MicrosoftProgram_Install_and_Uninstall.meta.diagcab from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed
  And removed everything with SSMS or management studio in the name. After that, SSMS 18.0 preview still appears in add/remove programs and an uninstall gives the same error as above.
- msiexec /x “{D620DE9C-8A83-4BA5-83A8-E709A4150A47}” brings up the same dialog so I cannot progress:

[image]

- Reinstall SSMS 18.0 Public Preview 6 works fine from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2052501
- Try and install SSMS 18 GA again and get a different error of:

[image]

- Remove SSMS 18 preview 6 via Add/Remove programs, and get the same error:

[image]

**Question**

How can I remove SSMS 18 preview? I don’t have vs2017_isoshell_for_ssms.msi, a web search for this file gives nothing and a re-install of the preview version does not provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two msi files are required to remove SSMS 18 preview:

1. vs2017_isoshell_for_ssms.msi
2. help3_vs_net.msi

I got the files off a colleague and put them in Downloads.

When the remove fails, the following dialog appears:

[image]

- Fails
- Browse to vs2017_isoshell_for_ssms.msi
- OK
- Fails
- Browse to help3_vs_net.msi
- OK
- Removes successfully:

[image]

I then:

- Installed Redgate tools in SSMS 18 GA (they didn't install on SSMS 18 preview)
- Removed SSMS 17.9 successfully via Add/Remove programs

**All fixed**

Answer (score 6):

From the command line, I was able to uninstall a different 18.0 preview (I don't have 6 anywhere):

```
msiexec /x "{2051D5D4-618D-4B9F-BA64-C1AE19003F2E}"
```

But I did not have the error about the shell msi, and I'm not sure if the CLSID changed, so I'm not sure that will work for you. (I'm not convinced the GUID in the dialog you're getting is the one you need for SSMS.)

Stolen shamelessly from [my own blog post about uninstalling Evaluation Edition](https://sqlblog.org/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition) which fails if the product has expired.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how recent your install is, it may just be quicker to revert to a prior system restore point, so long as you have the feature enabled.  They're pretty fast and pretty failsafe from my experience.

From the [Recovery options in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options#section1) support article:

> This option takes your PC back to an earlier point in time, called a
>   system restore point. Restore points are generated when you install a
>   new app or driver, and when you [create a restore point
>   manually](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027538). Restoring
>   won’t affect your personal files, but it will remove apps, drivers,
>   and updates installed after the restore point was made.
>
> 1. In the search box on the taskbar, type **control panel**, and then choose it from the list of results
> 2. In the **Control Panel** search box, type **recovery**.
> 3. Select **Recovery** > **Open System Restore**.
> 4. In the **Restore system files and setting** box, select **Next**.
> 5. Select the restore point that you want to use in the list of results, and then select **Scan for affected programs**.
> 6. You'll see a list of items that will be deleted if you remove this restore point. If you're OK with the deletions, select **Close** > **Next** >
>      **Finish**.
>
> Notes
>
> - If you don’t see the restore point that you want to use, select the **Show more restore points** check box to see more restore points.
> - If you’re not seeing any restore points, it might be because system protection isn’t turned on. Here’s how to check:
>
>   1. In the search box on the taskbar, type **control panel**, and then choose it from the list of results.
>   2. In the **Control Panel** search box, type **recovery**.
>   3. Select **Recovery** > **Configure System Restore** > **Configure** and see if the **Turn on system protection option** is selected.
>
>      - If the **Turn on system protection** option is not selected, system protection isn’t turned on and there aren't any restore points.
>          In this scenario, you won't be able to recovery your PC using a system
>          restore point and will need to use one of the other recovery options
>          listed on this page.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed a similar issue with a different package before - what seemed to happen in my case is that the GUID the installer was using was wrong. What you can try is reinstalling Preview 6, then keep an eye on your `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\` folder while the installer is running.

Typically it will extract all of the components of itself there, and one of the subfolders should contain the *.MSI* that you are missing. On my machine it's `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{AAA9F15B-AF45-4562-9991-93A848D3A902}v15.0.28307.421\redist\vs2017_isoshell_for_ssms.msi`, but it might be different on yours. Grab a copy of the *.MSI* before completing the install, then when you uninstall you can point the installer to the location of your copy of the *.MSI*.

Note that there might be a couple of MSI's that it can't locate if it's gotten into this state, so I'd be tempted to just grab all of the files while they are there. Often the installer will clean itself up after it's done, so timing might be a little tricky.

Comment: Thanks MDCCL, still getting to grips with the formatting!